# Fetch an object with a query by using foreign keys : ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, associations

i have these models.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :balls
end
    
class Ball < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :balls_owners
end
      
class BallsOwner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ball
  belongs_to :wallet
end
    
class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :balls_owners
end
    
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :wallets
end
```

I want to approach the user table.

i tried this query on console

```
company.balls.last.balls_owners
```

and it gives me the ball owner. now i only have wallt_id in balls_owner table how can i get the related wallet then from wallet to get user.

what should i have to add in above query to go further?

i used joins `company.balls.last.balls_owners.joins(:wallet).where(wallet: {id: wallet_id})`

but it returns the respected objects of balls_owners table but i need to get respected wallets.

Comment: I'd suggest including a slightly more specific example, including the actual code that doesn't work, something like:

```
class M1
  belongs_to :m2
end

class M2
  belongs_to :m3
  has_many :m1
end

class M3
  has_many :m2s
end
```

> And I tried running `...` and I get the result `...`, which is not what I expect

As of now the question is a little unclear

Comment: Since you appear to be looking for `User` objects start there `User.joins(wallets: { balls_owners: :ball}).where(balls: {company_id: company.id})`